# Can you help me with iterating list in python without loops

Tags: python, loops, iterator

```
class MyNumbers:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.a = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
    self.i = -1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    x = self.a
    i = self.i
    i += 1
    return x[i]

myclass = MyNumbers()
myiter = iter(myclass)

print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
```

i wanted it to iterate but result is only 3 times red. i want to see result like:
red
blue
green

Comment: Since `self.i` remains at `-1`, `i` will always be `0`. You'll need to increment `self.i` instead, and use `self.i` to index `x`: `return x[self.i]`. No temporary variable `i` needed. Also, no temporary `x` needed: `self.i += 1; return self.a[self.i]` is enough for `__next__`.

Comment: You never change `i`, `self.i += 1` `return x[self.i]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `i = self.i` you copy value from `self.i` to `i` and you increase only `i` but not `self.i` - and later you copy the same value from `self.i` to `i`.

You should increase `self.i` without using `i`.

```
class MyNumbers:
    
  def __iter__(self):
    self.a = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
    self.i = -1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    self.i += 1
    return self.a[self.i]

myclass = MyNumbers()
myiter = iter(myclass)

print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
```